# HTML5 video ended event called several times

Tags: javascript, html, events, video

I have a problem with playing a video in HTML5 and the ended Event.
I view some HTML content and after a expired time I play a video. Is the video ended I will show the HTML content again. This should loop. Its for a presentation.

My problem is, that after the first complete run, the ended event will fired repeatedly and the HTML content will displayed false.

Here is the code part:

```
function playVideo() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        $('video').hide();
        fadeShow();
    }, false);
    video.play();  
}

function fadeHide() {
    $('#content').fadeOut(1200, function () {
        $('div ul[id^=item]').each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('li[class^=visitor] span[id]').each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        playVideo();
    });
}
```

The `fadeHide();` function will not called two times, just the `video.addEventListener('ended', function () {};` fill called several times. `fadeshow(); will display the HTML content. Actually I use the newest version of Chrome.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

**Edit**
HTML video code. I hide the video with css.

```
<video>
    <source src="video/mp4/xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video/ogg/xxx.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video/webm/xxx.webm" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Greetz

Comment: Can you make a testcase in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Look here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vupz2/24/). Same Problem, after the video was showed two times. I show with an alert the call of `fadeShow();`. Sorry i havent found a shorter video.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should assign the event listener once or when you assign it upon play everytime, you need to detach the event listener again.

```
function playVideo() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        $('video').hide();
        video.removeEventListener('ended'); <<<<<<<
        fadeShow();
    }, false);
    video.play();  
}
```

**EDIT**: I tested in chrome with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9rt9/) and indeed even if you remove the eventlistener it starts to fire multiple times. It seems there's an issue that removing the event listener does not work correctly.

You should change the event binding / unbinding to jQuery then there is only one ended event.

```
function playVideo() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    $('video').bind('ended', function () {
        $('video').unbind('ended');
        $('video').hide();
        fadeShow();
    });
    video.play();  
}
```

And [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vupz2/27/) updated (with shorter video)

Comment: Ohh, you right! How could i missed this :). I will add the event just once. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe a few words for explanation: every time you call `playVideo` a **new** event handler is created, whereas all previously created ones will remain instead of being overwritten. That's why it works correctly the first time and starts firing multiple times afterwards.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thanks for extended explanation. +1

Comment: Sorry, but the problem still exist. I tested it with the `removeEventListener` method. Same problem. I checked if I really call the `play();` method only one time, that’s ok. What else could went wrong?
In the debugger I saw, that the play part will only called one time. After the video ends the event will raised and the event will be removed. Then the content will displayed and after that the `fadeShow();` function will called multiple times.

Comment: @hofmeister how does your html part look for the video ?

Comment: Please see my edit. If the `ended` event called, the `video.play();` line after that event will not executed,  or I’m wrong? Ok, that is rubbish :).

Comment: Wow. create job and good answer. Thank you very much. You saved my day :).

Comment: thank you. I have a script that is doing  recursion to sort through a  JSON fill it was a nightmare to find what as calling the functions  twice. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an event listener and then manually removing it, try simply using the built in command called "one" (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#one-first-second-third-)

So your code will become somewhat like this:

```js
function playVideo() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    $('video').one('ended', function () {
        $('video').hide();
        fadeShow();
    });
    video.play();  
}
```

Which is a little brief, and more dependent on the API itself. That I believe is generally a good practice because the functions in the API have been tested multiple times by a large number of people in the community over multiple browsers and operating systems.